# Magento 2 unknown error on exception.log

Tags: magento2, error

Keep getting below error every 5 minutes in exception log:

> [2018-06-20 04:35:05] main.CRITICAL: Item
>   (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor) with the same ID "704"
>   already exists. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Item
>   (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor) with the same ID
>   \"704\" already exists. at
>   /vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php:404)"} []

Comment: Please do indexing 1 more time

Answer (score 0):

To quickly fix it you can delete all rows that have duplicated products IDs in `cataloginventory_stock_item` table.

Answer (score 0):

solved, by finding the Product and then re-save it again then re index.